# resolve matrix lists with lambda and map

Tags: python, list, matrix, lambda

we have 3 lists in below

```
    [2,3,4]
    [5,6,7]
    [8,9,10]
```

so , how we can sum all of similar index in lists together?
i mean is 2 and 5 and 8 be sum together & 3 and 6 and 9 also be sum together & 4 and 7 and 10 as well ? but just use lambda and map...

actually i have no idea for that and this code is just for sending this question

```
    x=[
    [5,8,1],
    [9,4,7],
    [2,6,3],
    ]
    
    
    print(list(map(lambda x : x[1], x)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get them all together use `zip`:

```
new = list((zip(*matrix)))
```

output:

```
[(2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (4, 7, 10)]
```

to sum them up you can use `sum` and `map`:

```
sum = list(map(sum, zip(*matrix)))
```

output:

```
[15, 18, 21]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` your input data:

```
matrix = [[2,3,4],
          [5,6,7],
          [8,9,10]]

out = list(map(sum, zip(*matrix)))
```

Or using a list comprehension:

```
out = [sum(x) for x in zip(*matrix)]
```

Output: `[15, 18, 21]`